# JSON Schema not validating required field when it is an empty string

Tags: json, mule, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm using mule validate JSON schema component to validate my incoming json request.
It validates the type but not the required field attributes

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "properties": {
    "Employees": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "BirthDate": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
          },
          "EmpNum": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "FirstName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Gender": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "LastName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "LicenseNumber": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "ZipCode": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": ["EmpNum", "LastName", "FirstName", "Street", "ZipCode", "BirthDate" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have json as shown below:

```
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "EmpNum": 3,
      "FirstName": "Finder",
      "LastName": "Path",
      "Street": "392 CDI CDIJUW",
      "ZipCode": "12345",
      "BirthDate": "1943-05-19T04:00:00Z",
      "Gender": "M"
    },
    {
       "EmpNum": 3,
      "FirstName": "",
      "LastName": "Path",
      "Street": "392 CDI CDIJUW",
      "ZipCode": "12345",
      "BirthDate": "1943-05-19T04:00:00Z",
      "Gender": "M"
    }
  ]
}
```

Even though I have set a field to an empty string, it still takes as a valid request and proceeds further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you intentionally set FirstName to be an empty string and want to invalidate it, try adding minLength:

```
      "FirstName": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
      },
```

Comment: Ah, so the issue was that you expected empty string to be the same as omitting the field @Pathfinder? (I've updated the question to reflect this, so please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I havent noticed that only empty strings are not validated previously but after I came to notice minLength then I came to know that only empty strings are not validated... So as per your question you are correct :)

Comment: hi @Pathfinder this will accept a blank string (like one space). Do you know which is the best way to filter that case too?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I would assume it will accept it. You can add a `"pattern" : "<regex_pattern>"` to check for specific values/patterns, including checking for whitespace (which is an entirely different battle ;)).